# load different data in table on selection of different options using dropdown in angular?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, drop-down-menu

i have a dropdown and an json file i want to load two different data from a json file using each option from dropdown i am not getting how to do it.

here is my drop down code and i am taking the drop down data also from a json type file created in controller

```
 <select ng-model="appointment" name="appointment-sch" ng-options="item as item.name for item in selectItemsFilterCriteria">
                <option value="">Filter Criteria</option>
            </select>
```

i am taking options into drop down like this into the controller

```
 $scope.selectItemsFilterCriteria = [
    {id:1 , name:"appointments scheduled"},
    {id:2 , name:"fresh leads"}

  ];
```

i have data into my json file, now i want my data to be sorted according to the option selected from the dropdown and show that into a simple table

this i my service

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('n.lead-allocation')
        .factory('factoryLeadAlloc',function($http) {
            function fetchLeadRecord() {
                return $http({
                    url: "../www/jsonFiles/leadAllocRecord.json",
                    method: "GET"
                });
            }
            return{
                fetchLeadRecord:fetchLeadRecord
            }
        });
})();
```

i am calling this service into controller and storing services json data into item array.

```
$scope.items = [];
        factoryLeadAlloc.fetchLeadRecord().success(function(response) {
          $scope.items = response;
          $scope.search = function () {
            $scope.filteredItems = $filter('filter')($scope.items, function (item) {
              return searchMatch(item.name, $scope.query) || searchMatch(item.phoneNo, $scope.query);
              //for(var attr in item) {
              //  if (searchMatch(item[attr], $scope.query))
              //
              //    return true;
              //}
              //return false;
            });
      // take care of the
```

Comment: can you share the code, how  u r loading json data

Comment: okay this is just a wild guess i personally would use ng-change on your select  so everytime the value changes your change function is called and in there you just filter your items and create the array / object for your table data

Comment: can i have an example of that bcz i m new to angular i donno the full options available with it

Answer (score 0):

okay I tried to put together a Codepen for you which should clarify how you could change the data
  [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGjOqW)

```
 $scope.changeTable = function(id){
    angular.forEach($scope.people, function(value, index){
        console.log(value.id)
        if(id == value.id){
        $scope.displayList.push(value);
        }
    });
    console.log($scope.displayList);
}
```

Comment: i got ur code but i am not able to implement it into my code as the requirement is different you are taking data from the same array i have 2 json type files one is showing the list for dropdown and another contains the data

Comment: okay i updated my codepen now you have 2 different Arrays when you change the dropdown the matching Part from array 2 is listed, so the only thing you need is too match dropdown Value with the other data array pretty much the same you do

Comment: the only important thing is the IF statement in the angular.forEach, there u need to say ok if the first in the dropdown is selected, then only push specific elements into the List